# Why is assigning a variable with a class, which constructs a thread working faster than aborting the thread instead?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I would like to run a thread and abort it when I need to run it again while the thread can be still alive, but I noticed that aborting is slow due to how [aborting](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.abort?view=netframework-4.8) a thread works.

Therefore I have the following implementation of simulations, which construct threads and measure the time for the simulation:

```
private Thread _t;

public void Main()
{
    SimulateAbortThread();
    SimulateThreadClass();
}

private void SimulateAbortThread()
{
    var sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        RunThread();
    }
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

}

private void RunThread()
{
    if (_t != null && _t.IsAlive) _t.Abort();
    _t = new Thread(() =>
    {
        //doStuff();
    });
    _t.Start();
}

private void SimulateThreadClass()
{
    var thread = new ThreadClass();
    var sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        thread = new ThreadClass();
    }
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}

private class ThreadClass
{
    public ThreadClass()
    {
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            //doStuff();
        }).Start();
    }
}
```

I discovered that creating a new instance of a class, which constructs a new thread, is faster than aborting the thread itself. The results of both simulations in real cases are identical but, due to how aborting works the simulations only differ in speed, which is why I am currently using the second simulation.

I would like to know, why the second simulation is running faster and how I can avoid assigning a variable a new instance of a class to "restart" threads while they still might run?

Comment: Calling `Thread.Abort()` is a bad thing to do unless you are forcibly trying to shutdown your app. Do not use it to manage the lifetime of your threads. The only safe way to manage threads is cooperatively.

Comment: Your test proves that starting and aborting 100 threads is slower that starting 100 threads without aborting them. Why is this surprising? Doing more work should always be slower than doing less work. Did you assume that the mere existence of the other threads would slow down the current thread? Btw keep in mind that the `Thread.Abort` method is not supported on .NET Core. Attempting to use it results to a `PlatformNotSupportedException`.

Comment: @Enigmativity And if you're forcibly shutting down the app, it makes even less sense to use abort. Don't sweep the floors in a building that's about to be torn down as Raymond Chen would say. Just let the OS take care of it. There's literally no situation I can think of where abort is the right choice.

Comment: @Voo - What about a situation where a loose thread prevents your app shutting down? Background threads automatically end, but not where `IsBackground` is `false`.

Comment: @Enigmativity In .NET if you want to forcibly terminate your application you shouldn't just return from the main thread, but call `Environment.Exit` which in turn then calls `ExitProcess` or `TerminateProcess` on Windows and similar things on other OSes. The OS will then take care of the whole process whether other threads want it or not. Note also that contrary to `Thread.Abort` which I can easily work around (little known fact on modern CLRs but true), it's a good deal harder for `Environment.Exit` (it'd be interesting to know which win32 API is used)

Comment: @Voo - Can you please breakdown the sentence "Note also that contrary to Thread.Abort which I can easily work around (little known fact on modern CLRs but true), it's a good deal harder for Environment.Exit (it'd be interesting to know which win32 API is used) " into clear sentences for me?

Comment: Constrained execution regions trump Thread.Abort (since CRL 4.0 iirc), then there's good old Thread.ResetAbort() (whoever thought that one was a good idea, I'd love to meet). If I call `TerminateProcess` on the other hand, no user code will be able to stop termination. With `ExitProcess` you still execute user code in the native library unload functions so that could be abused (but requires native code).